# Get with ffmpeg first and last frame images

Tags: ffmpeg

It is possible to get first and last frames with using ffmpeg and only one system call?

If I know duration
`ffmpeg -ss 00:00:00 -i input.mov -vf fps=1/duration -vframes 2 -q:v 1 -qmin 1 out%2d.jpg`
is working but not right.
But I need second system call for recieving duration video.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because , as explained by the ffmpeg tag: Only questions about programmatic use of the FFmpeg libraries, API, or tools are on topic. Questions about interactive use of the command line tool should be asked on https://superuser.com/ or https://video.stackexchange.com/. Please delete this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ffmpeg has an option to seek relative to the end. You can use that to get to the last frame. To make this efficient, we will use the source as an input twice.

`ffmpeg -i input.mov -sseof -1 -i input.mov -map 0:v -vframes 1 -q:v 1 -qmin 1 first.jpg -map 1:v -q:v 1 -qmin 1 -update 1 last.jpg`